# TypeScript -- new Image() from global scope

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class MYMODULE.Image{}, but I want to instantiate an object of type HTMLImageElement. When I call `new Image()`, TypeScript thinks I want to instantiate MYMODULE.Image, even when I use

```
image: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
```

Can I somehow explicitly call the global Image class? I tried

`image: HTMLImageElement = new Window.Image();` but to no avail.

A scope resolution operator like C++'s `::Image` would be handy. Perhaps it's there and I just don't see it.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Creating a HTMLImage element can be done like this.

`document.createElement("img");`

According to the Mozilla documentation it is the same: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.Image

Edit:

If you want to use the Image constructor you might need to create a new interface like below:

```
interface Window {
    Image: {   
        prototype: HTMLImageElement;
        new (): HTMLImageElement;
    };
}
var a = new window.Image()
```

Comment: Nope, it looks like TypeScript which compiles to JavaScript ;)

Comment: I accept 

    document.createElement("img");

as an answer because it is the most hassle free. Thank you for interesting answers!

Check out [http://www.sympad.nl/four_in_a_row/][1] for my latest experiment in TypeScript


  [1]: http://www.sympad.nl/four_in_a_row/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a clever use of `typeof` :

```
declare var imageType:typeof Image; // Create a alias so you can refer to the type 
interface Window{
    // Use the `typeof alias` because `Image` would be confused in the context
    Image: typeof imageType; 
}
```

Complete sample:

```
declare var imageType:typeof Image;
interface Window{
    Image: typeof imageType;
}

module Foo{
    class Image{}

    var image: HTMLImageElement = new window.Image();
}
```