# new window.Image() is not working with typescript / react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, konvajs

I am using the library KonvasJs for React. (https://github.com/lavrton/react-konva#using-images)

To load an image in javascript/React it is

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const image = new window.Image();
    image.src = "http://konvajs.github.io/assets/yoda.jpg";
    image.onload = () => {
      // setState will redraw layer
      // because "image" property is changed
      this.setState({
        image: image
      });
    };
  }
```

It works fine.
When I switch Typescript, I have this error: 
[image]

I have tried also to add:

```
interface Window {
    Image: typeof Image;
}
```

or

```
  interface Windows extends Window {
      Image: typeof Image;
  }
```

or

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
      Image: typeof Image;
  }
}
```

Without success

[image]
or
[image]
Any ideas?

Related issues:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10241

[TypeScript -- new Image() from global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203906/typescript-new-image-from-global-scope?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/337/how-to-declare-a-new-property-on-the-window-object-with-typescript

https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/5fieja/how_do_i_add_a_property_to_window_in_typescript_2/

Answer (score 1):

Solution is :

```
const image = new (window as any).Image()
image.src = './dragFile.png'
image.onload = () => {
  this.setState({
    image: image
  })
}
```

source: https://github.com/Microsoft/reactxp/blob/master/src/web/Image.tsx#L139

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not including the `DOM` library.

If you're using a tsconfig.json, include the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Or if using the CLI:

```
tsc --lib dom ...
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do include the dom and it is still not working: "lib": ["es6", "dom"],

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the following [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Since you're using KonvajS, they override the global `Image` definition with their own type which breaks the default Image HTMLImageElement DOM type

If you're using stricter tslint rules that don't allow `any` keyword then this solution would work:

```
interface IHTMLImageElement {
  prototype: HTMLImageElement
  new(): HTMLImageElement
}

declare global {
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  interface Window {
    Image: IHTMLImageElement
  }
}
```